# How to knock a hole through wall in crawl space

Tags: walls, insulation, crawlspace

I need to gett access to the crawl space under the floors in every room in my house so that I can fit underfloor insulation.

I'd like to fit insulation board as it seems to be the easiest to work with. At the moment I have a single access hatch - 400 x 500mm  which is big enough to get me and materials through.

There are then 3 walls that extende below the floor which I need access through and currently don't have it:

1. A sleeper wall (no wall continues above floor level) which is a single layer of bricks, has lots of ventilation holes (missing half bricks) but no access hole.
2. A single-layer brick wall which extends above the floor and currently has a small hole in it (350 x 300mm) - *just* big enough for me, but not ideal for getting insulation panels through
3. A double-layer brick wall which also ectends above the floor, and also has a small access hole in it (350 x 300mm).

My options for gaining access to below the floor in each space seem to be either to make more access hatches/holes through the floor boards (one in each room), or to knock larger access holes through the sub-floor walls. I'd prefer not to cut more holes in my floors, so my questions are relating to how to best knock bigger holes through the walls:

1. What tool would I need to cut through a double brick wall - I have a 125mm angle grinder with diamond cutting disk which might just get me through 1 layer of brick, but not sure even a 230mm grinder would get me through 2 layers?

   2. How do I go about sizing a Lintel? - I've seen advice on length which is easy (free span + 150mm end bearing each end) - but not sure how to know what load-rating of lintel is required.
   3. Do I need to support the walls whilst the space for the lintel is cut and lintel is installed (e.g. jacks under the joists either side of the wall)?
   4. Any other advice?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's often easiest to attack a brick or block wall at the mortar vs. attempting to saw through the bricks/blocks.  Also, however, be sure you do NOT compromise the load carrying function of the walls you are attempting to cut.  If in doubt, consult a structural engineer.

Comment: "I'd like to fit insulation board as it seems to be the easiest to work with" - probably not, if that means cutting holes in a brick wall. Definitely not, if you have to put a lintel. Use batt insulation and the existing holes, or go buy an SDS chipping hammer. Re., structural engineer: hammer: $5. Knowing where to use hammer: $5k....